# What online services provide on canvas printing?

Tags: printing, service-recommendation, canvas

Can anyone recommend an online provider and/or method of canvas printing of photographs? It doesn't need to be wrapped around gallery style stretched canvas, but just a way to remotely have photographs printed from a digital format to stretch canvas. Money, distance, etc are not factors. I'm more interested in process and quality of result.

Comment: What locale are you in? America, Europe, somewhere else? What are your budgetary requirements?

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/users/5750/mirezus says that he is in NY.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a first hand experience with their canvas prints, but [BayPhoto](http://www.bayphoto.com/canvas-prints/index.htm) did fine on my 20x16 foamcore mounted prints. Their prices seem to be in-line with comparative services and their customer service is very good as well. The submission of files is through a convenient Java applet (BayROES) that you download from their website and through which you manage your account.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [RGBdigital](http://rgbdigital.com.au/) in Brisbane Australia.
Here are the sizes and prices: http://rgbdigital.com.au/pricelist/canvas.html
They also use ROES for electronic orders.
They use quality Canson matte cotton canvas, printed on a large format Epson printer with archival inks, every canvas is custom made, frames are cut to size and canvas hand stretched.

Answer (score 0):

We offer great prices for archival certified canvas wraps.  Upload any picture to our site and we do all the work for you.  Check out our website @ http://www.squareonecanvas.com or on Facebook @ http://www.facebook.com/squareonecanvas

Answer (score 0):

There are several, plus, several blog posts across the web suggesting such services.

Here are a few:

- [Point 101](http://www.point101.com/) *(UK Based, ships to Europe, North America Far East and Australia)*
- [CanvasPop](http://www.canvaspop.com) *(US Based, ships to US & Canada only)*
- [Canvas R Us](http://www.canvasrus.eu/) *(Netherlands Based, ships to US, Europe and Australia)*
- [Your Image 2 Canvas](http://www.yourimage2canvas.co.uk/) *(UK Based, ships to Europe)*

Regarding an How to manually print and frame it, you can follow some nice Youtube tutorials, here is one in 2 parts:

- [Canvas - Printing and Framing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gs1xOsk-cso) (Part I)
- [Canvas - Printing and Framing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bU5JI1TFT0) (Part II)